# Multiple treatment group comparisons in a Generative Additive Mixed Model

Tags: multiple-comparisons, biostatistics, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I've fitted a GAMM using the `mgcv` package in R to some time course data from a biological experiment, with multiple drug treatment groups and a vehicle control group. I'm looking to make a comparison of each treatment group to the vehicle control. I have a linear fixed effect of the dummy encoded treatment group factor, and a separate time smoother has been applied for each treatment group.

My issue is that my GAMM has individual components for both the smoother I have applied on the time variable, and the linear term for the fixed effect of the treatment group. Naturally, I could fit individual models for each separate treatment vs. control, and conduct a LRT for each model against a null, but I was wondering whether there is some methodology that can utilise the full model instead.

If anyone has any guidance, it would be greatly appreciated, cheers :)